# Why is the question out-of-view of the answer box?

Tags: feature-request

For long questions with lots of details, and especially when there are already answers present, the answer form is out of view.  I have to scroll down to start answering, then I have to keep scrolling back up to see the original question while I'm answering, and then I have to scroll back down again to continue writing my answer, etc.  It all just feels very unnatural if this is supposed to be a "Q/A" site.

Is there a way to collapse all of the stuff in between so that the question is always in view while I'm answering?

Currently, I've been writing my answers in notepad.  Also because writing text in a browser can be a nightmare - it's often easy to accidentally navigate away, or submit an unfinished reply.  I didn't test it yet, but I hope that StackOverflow has addressed these issues as well.

Answer (score 5):

I feel a better solution to this would be to have the 'Your Answer' section be directly beneath the question - perhaps in a minimised state (for example, a button saying 'Add Your Answer' which would open up the full editor)

Comment: Agreed.  But I'm new to SO.  Why hasn't this been reported before like over 1000 times already?

Comment: Not entirely sure. I did a quick check on meta.stackexchange.com and didn't see it there, either...

Comment: Of course I don't know for certain, but I would imagine it's setup like this to "force" you to read the existing answers before posting your own. If that's the case, maybe putting an "Add Answer" button at the bottom of the page that would open the editor directly under the question might accomplish both goals.

Comment: @MikeM. Good points.